# Can Vampires Take Form of Nocturnal Animals?

Tags: mythical-creatures, folklore, vampires

In Bram Stoker's Dracula, it was hinted that he may have taken form of a bat while visiting the asylum inmate, Renfield. Is that possible? And could he take form of all the other animals, like wolves or owls?

Comment: Welcome to Mythology!  In popular culture, the bat form certainly gained a lot of traction.  (The [Twilight Watch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twilight_Watch) treats this somewhat humorously, where the bats are human-sized.)   I'm pretty sure I've come across references to other animal forms for vampires, but I suspect they are modern.

Comment: If you are asking specifically about Dracula, which is a novel not a myth, you may get a better answer on Literature.SE.

Answer (score 1):

if I remember right it's also suggested he turns into a large dog at some point in London so the dog or wolf could be possible.
do you specifically mean European vampires because most cultures have some folklore on undead that feed on blood

Comment: Yes, I suppose so, as I am doing an essay for Dracula,(The book) and the reasons or theories behind the tropes used.